# Mesh with different materials unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

How do I create a mesh in unity via script to use two different materials?

Comment: Do really mean create in Unity or using a mesh, that is created in 3D modeling tool, as game object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all the information you need in [here](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.html), unless like Kay said you  don't really mean to **create** the mesh in Unity directly.

To assign two different materials to a mesh I think you need to break that mesh in two and assign separately. I'm doing something like this and I just keep the vertices[] and separate the triangles[]. Works for me.